# Different objects but same value?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, object

I have a problem when i tried to change of the value.

```
List<RefLanguage> languages1 = _refLanguageService.GetAll();
List<RefLanguage> languages2 = languages1;
languages1.Where(x => x.Id == 1).ToList().ForEach(x => x.Name = "Turkish");
Boolean isSame = languages1.Equals(languages2);
```

The first line is getting RefLanguage records by using EF.

When i execute the code, the value of isSame object is TRUE.

Comment: And also `Equals` compares just references between two objects, not items inside lists.

Comment: when i change the value in language1 which 's id is 1. languages2 also changed. is it true ?

Comment: Do you know what a debugger is? This is a duplicate of plenty of questions, try searching.

Comment: It's expected behavior because you are trying to compare the same object. 

`List<RefLanguage> languages2 = languages1;` is not copy anything actually you just put the reference from one variable to another but you still have one list. 

If you will add new element to the `languages2` then the `languages1` will contains this element too because it is still two equals references to the same object.

You can read more about value types and reference types [on MSDN][1].


  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx

Comment: @CodeCaster i also use runtime cache before GetAll method. is it ok if also the object is changed in the memory ?

Comment: A reference is a reference.

Answer (score 3):

The line `List<RefLanguage> languages2 = languages1;` points the reference of `languages1` to the same memory as `languages2`. The `.Equals` method will then compare the two references, which in this case are the same.

What you instead can do to compare is

```
bool isSame = languages1.SequenceEqual(languages2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [.Equals method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to check the reference. In your case when you say

```
List<RefLanguage> languages2 = languages1;
```

You are making both the reference equal or point to the same memory and hence true as result.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `languages2` to `languages1` you reference the same list under two different variables, your where-statement won´t change anything to that as where simply creates a new data-structure (an iterator).

What you want to do actually is creating a new list based on the former by:

```
var languages2 = languages1.Where(...).ToList().
```

However the elements within both lists are still the same, thus when you modify any element from `languages1` it will be reflected in the other list also.

Comment: Assuming `RefLanguage` is a reference type, this will create a new list, but still pointing to the same objects. Updating an object in list 1 will update the same object in list 2.

Comment: @CodeCaster I assume that is exactly what OP wants: reference the same objects from two different lists.